# Chromecast connection lost after screen lock

Tags: android, chromecast

I have integrated the latest cast SDK within my Android application. It does play media correctly and I'm able to control the playback via on-screen controls as well as via the status bar notification and lock-screen.

I have received, though, reports from some users saying that after a while listening to the media via cast, when their devices *went to sleep*/*got locked*, they were not in sync with the receiver anymore as well as losing the possibility of controlling the playback.
I was not able to consistently reproduce the issue (since forcefully locking the device keeps the connection *for a while*), but I could see it happening a number of times and was able to catch logs for one of them.

At first, I was suspecting that the receiver's messages were not arriving to the sender (android app), but the `Google Home` application works flawlessly and updates the metadata and playback controls correctly. So, the pain point must be in my application.

I did notice that, while in that "inconsistent state", I am still able to read logs after a track finishes (so, change of state) as follows:

`02-05 00:02:08.958 16642-27384/? W/CastDeviceController: [controller-0335 API] Ignoring message. Namespace 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media' has not been registered.`

Do I need to register that protocol within my application? (I do use a custom protocol to **send** messages - and if I'm not mistaken, the "unregistered protocol" is the default one - shouldn't it be automatically registered?). If so, how can I perform that registration?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to check this [page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/ynaShtsmirE) if it can help you? This connection issue sometime caused by the TV model and the OS that is used for this.

Comment: @KENdi Unfortunately the problem is not related to the TV model. I can see it happening in different setups but couldn't figure out a way to reproduce it consistently yet.